# how to update a collection after updating the api

Tags: postman

I am using postman to create a [collection](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/design-and-develop-apis/the-api-workflow/#generating-a-collection) from an API (schema `OpenAPI 3.0`)

I create a collection by clicking on the "Generate Collection"

[image]

I can then go to the collection, do some requests and so far all good, but if I modify something in the API schema, how could I update the collection without having to create a new one?